# Save hundreds of PFObjects to Parse cloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I have an application where I have two parse tables - "User" and "Topics". Now what I want is that if any user signs up, then I want to create another parse table which will store some info related to that user and the topic say topic progress. Here's my code -

```
- (IBAction)signUpFunction {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSString *fullName = self.nameTextField.text;
    NSString *username = self.usernameTextField.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordTextField.text;
    NSString *email = self.emailTextField.text;
    if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0 || [email length] == 0 || [fullName length] == 0) 
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                                message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!"
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
    else {
        PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
        newUser.username = username;
        newUser.password = password;
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser[@"fullName"] = fullName;
        [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {

                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show ];
            }
            else 
            {
                PFQuery *topicsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Topic"];
                [topicsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)       {
                    if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);     
                    }
                    else {

                        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {
                            PFObject *object = objects[i];
                            PFObject *topicProgressForUser = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"QuizProgress"];
                            [topicProgressForUser setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user"];
                            [topicProgressForUser setObject:object forKey:@"topic"];

                            if ([object[@"fullAccess"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
                                [topicProgressForUser setObject:@"Free" forKey:@"purchased"];
                            } else {
                                [topicProgressForUser setObject:@"No" forKey:@"purchased"];
                            }
                            [topicProgressForUser setObject:0 forKey:@"questionsSolved"];
                            [topicProgressForUser setObject:0 forKey:@"attempts"];
                            [topicProgressForUser setObject:0 forKey:@"resultInPercentage"];
                            [topicProgressForUser setObject:@"Basic" forKey:@"achievement"];
                            [topicProgressForUser setObject:NO forKey:@"generateCertificate"];

                            [topicProgressForUser saveEventually];

                        }
                    }
                }]; // topic block

            }
        }]; // signup block
     }
}
```

I don't think I am using the right standard of saving data to parse cloud by saving each pfobject individually. What if the internet connection is lost in the middle of saving objects ? Can anyone help me in using the correct and fast approach of saving multiple pfobject data to new table in parse cloud.

Comment: Check the doc, you can save arrays of PFObjects in one query, it's gonna make your life 100% better and your requests count 100000% better too :D

Comment: Yes Zil, you are right. I came to know about adding the PFObjects in an array and then saving the array using "saveAllInBackground". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would take a look at the class methods `saveAll`, `saveAllInBackground`, etc.

I took your code and modified it how I think makes the most sense in this case. Let me know if it works:

```
- (IBAction)signUpFunction {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSString *fullName = self.nameTextField.text;
    NSString *username = self.usernameTextField.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordTextField.text;
    NSString *email = self.emailTextField.text;
    if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0 || [email length] == 0 || [fullName length] == 0) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                                    message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    } else {
        PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
        newUser.username = username;
        newUser.password = password;
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser[@"fullName"] = fullName;
        [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show ];
            } else {
                PFQuery *topicsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Topic"];
                [topicsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    } else {
                        NSMutableArray *topics = [NSMutableArray array];
                        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {
                            PFObject *object = objects[i];
                            PFObject *topicProgressForUser = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"QuizProgress"];
                            [topics addObject:topicProgressForUser];
                            topicProgressForUser[@"user"]                   = [PFUser currentUser];
                            topicProgressForUser[@"topic"]                  = object;
                            topicProgressForUser[@"questionSolved"]         = @(NO);
                            topicProgressForUser[@"attempts"]               = @(0);
                            topicProgressForUser[@"resultInPercentage"]     = @(0);
                            topicProgressForUser[@"achievement"]            = @"Basic";
                            topicProgressForUser[@"generateCertificate"]    = @(NO);
                            if ([object[@"fullAccess"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
                                topicProgressForUser[@"purchased"]  = @"Free";
                            } else {
                                topicProgressForUser[@"purchased"]  = @"No";
                            }
                        }
                        [PFObject saveAllInBackground:objects block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                            if (error != nil) {
                                // Do something here to handle the error

                            } else {
                                //
                            }
                        }
                         ]; // saveAllInBackground
                    }
                }]; // topic block
            }
        }]; // signup block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line of code:

```
[topicProgressForUser saveEventually];
```

to

```
[topicProgressForUser saveInBackground];
```

Hope this helps..